# ¿Cómo puedo poner una imagen en un cilindro en wpf C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

necesito poner una imagen en un cilindro usando WPF o como darle ese efecto a una imagen [image: como en este cilindro. Ese efecto de curvatura y profundidad pero para una imagen]

Comment: Bryan. ¿Haz realizado alguna investicacion previa acerca de las posibilidades que te ofrece WPF para graficos? ¿Haz intentado utilizar alguna? ¿Si ya haz intentado algo deberías publicar la parte del código que se acerca a lo que estas intentando para, así focalizada, poder dar la solucion que buscas.

Comment: Mauricio. soy nuevo usando wpf ,aun no he comenzado con el codigo , pero lo quería hacer por medio de wpf porque es algo que no hasta mucho recursos como puede ser el caso de trabajar en uniti o blender con modelos 3d

Comment: Y ese cilindro de donde lo sacaste? coloca parte de tu código para saber como estás haciendo tu ventana.